# whats the sql syntax error in this query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am unable to find out here what's the error syntax.
[image]

Comment: Please add your code and error [as text instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: try it without ;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-G), `GROUPS` is a **reserved keyword**, starting with MySQL 8.0.2.

You should seriously consider renaming your table.

Comment: I really appreciate in your support. before I have no idea about reserved keyword. thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove ";" this character